# Error when trying to import from Database with Pandas and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using portable python 2.7.6.1 and I want to import a query from an oracle database into python pandas. I have searched a couple of examples and came up with the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('oracle://user:pass@host:port/schema', echo=False)
df = pd.read_sql('select * from databasetable', engine, index_col = index)

print df.describe()
```

The program stops at the 'pd.read_sql'-statement with this Error Message:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_sql'
```

The Database connection is working and according to the examples this code should work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your code correct, you have double single quotes in your param to `create_engine` also for your sql statement, does it work if you pass a raw string: `df = pd.read_sql(r'select * from databasetable', engine, index_col = index)`

Comment: the 'create engine' works without errors. I have tried the raw string and I am getting the same error. It feels as if the 'read_sql' is not found in pandas. But this seems odd to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas module imports read_sql from a submodule; you could try getting it from the submodule:

```
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql('select * from databasetable', engine, index_col = index)
```

You could also print `pd.__dict__` to see what's available in the `pd` module. Do you get `AttributeError` if you try to use other things from the `pd` module, for example, `pd.Series()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have checked with pd.__dict__ and the on the pandas-docs for the versions. --> It seems in my version 0.11.0 'sql_read_frame' is the command to use and in Version 0.15.0 you can read sql with 'read_sql'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. 
I have checked with pd.**dict** and the on the pandas-docs for the versions. 
--> It seems in my version 0.11.0 `'sql_read_frame'` is the command to use and in Version 0.15.0 you can read sql with `'read_sql'`

Answer (score 0):

The method [`pandas.io.sql.read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.12.0/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_sql.html) was introduced in `pandas 0.12.0` (Release date: 2013-07-24).

[Change log](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/release.html#id19):

> io API changes: […] added top-level pd.read_sql and to_sql DataFrame methods